# package ros-groovy-desktop-full not found

Tags: ros, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm trying tin install ROS with the code sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63373/package-ros-groovy-desktop-full-not-found/) by [coughsyrup](https://answers.ros.org/users/4962/coughsyrup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to follow this install guide step by step: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu

Go through steps 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3 again.

---

Originally posted by [sobotacm](https://answers.ros.org/users/4956/sobotacm/) with karma: 36 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1